# Turing machine states design

Tags: automata, turing-machines

I want to design a Turing machine that accepts at most 3 0s. Now, I have designed one, which goes to accept state overtime it sees 1, 2 and 3 0s and rejects any further 0s. I wanted to know if it is okay for TM to go to accepting state from 3 different states?

Comment: You'd be better off asking such a question on [the Computer Science site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/93768/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51129854/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @Jonathon, may I make a request for the future?  In the future, if you suggest another site, can you let the poster know that they should not cross-post?  You can suggest they delete the copy here before posting elsewhere.  Hopefully this will provide a better experience for all.  Thanks for listening!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. Even if you want a deterministic machine, several transitions going into the same state are fine. If several outgoing transitions read the same symbol the machine is not deterministic anymore. But even this is not a problem for nondeterministic TMs.